# Conversion from json to decimal

Tags: java, regex, json

I have a JSON string.

```
{"bounds": {"south west":{ "lng":74.1475868, "lat": 31.366689}, "northeast": { "lng":74.85623 ,"lat": 32.5698746}}
```

I want to get integers with decimal values using regular expression in Java.

Comment: please do not use regex to parse JSON, XML, CSV or any other data format.

Comment: Why would you want to use Regex for this? Why not just parse the JSON?

Comment: liho1eye: While technically correct, there are no tricky ways of representing a number in JSON, thus this should work reasonably well.

Comment: @Jaffar You never really ask a question in your post. Try rephrasing it.

Answer (score 4):

JSON is not a regular language, and can therefore not be parsed by plain regular expressions (and parsing it with non-regular extensions of regular expressions is extremely complicated). Instead, use a [Java JSON library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex to parse structured documents. There are way better ways to do it. Now in case someone forced you to use regex to do this job by pointing a gun in your head you could use this :

```
try {
    Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("[-+]?\\b[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+\\b");
    Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(subjectString);
    while (regexMatcher.find()) {
        // matched text: regexMatcher.group()
        // match start: regexMatcher.start()
        // match end: regexMatcher.end()
    } 
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

This will catch all numbers integer or not negative or positive with optional integer part.

Note it will **not** match numbers with scientific notation!